# Modified Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path, heuristics

We are given a directed graph with edge weights W lying between 0 and 1. Cost of a path from source to target node is the product of the weights of edges lying on the path from source to target node. I wanted to know of an algorithm which can find the minimum cost path in polynomial time or using any other heuristic.

I thought along the lines of taking the log values of the edges weights (taking mod values) and then applying dijkstra for this graph but think there will be  precision problems which can't be calculated.

Is there any other better way or can I improve upon the log approach.

Comment: On the contrary - sum of logs will probably be more stable than successive products.

Comment: Dijkstra's does not work for negative edge lengths. Try using Bellman Ford's algorithm if the O(|V|.|E|) complexity suits you.

Answer (score 1):

In Dijkstra's algorithm, when you visit a node you know that there is no shorter road to this node. This is not true if you multiply the edges with weights between 0..1 as if you visit more vertices you will get a smaller number.

Basically this is equivalent of finding the longest path in a graph. This can be seen also by using your idea of taking logarithms, as the logarithm of a number between 0 and 1 is negative. If you take absolute values of the logarithms of the weights, the longest path corresponds to the shortest path in the multiplicative graph.

If your graph is acyclic there is a straightforward algorithm (modified from [Longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)).

1. Find a Topological ordering of the DAG.
2. For each vertex you need to store the cost of path. Initialize this to one at the beginning.
3. Travel through the DAG in topological order starting from your start vertex. In each vertex check all the children and if the cost is smaller than previously, update it. Store also the vertex where you arrive at this vertex with the lowest cost.

After you reach your final vertex, you can find the "shortest" path by travelling back from the end vertex using the stored vertices.

Of course, if you graph is not acyclic you can always reach a zero end cost by repeating a loop infinitely.